# How to find out MBA-2011 13" battery serial number on the battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, serial-number

I'm aware of ability to find out the battery serial number via About This Mac.

Is it also written somewhere on a physical battery, to be read without turning Mac on? If so, where?

Of course I'm ready to open the bottom cover of the computer to physically see the battery (and most likely to detach the battery from the Air to see the number on it).

I have Macbook Air 2011 13".

Comment: @Buscar웃 My question originally mentioned "Is it also written somewhere on a physical battery?". This implies that I need to physically access and see the battery. I am ready to clarify that in the original question for the sake of future readers and answers, but you don't want me to do that, judging by your revert?

Comment: I am willing to cooperate, but the question clearly asks if the serial number is written on the battery. That one can only be accessed by opening the computer. As said please clarify your question (and please do not use the implies/ assumptions). For example:  You want to know the battery serial number without using About this Mac and WITHOUT opening the computer to see the battery

Comment: "and WITHOUT opening the computer to see the battery": I want the opposite: I AM ready to open the computer to see the battery :-) And said that in two comments here, and I tried to say the same in the edit to the question (but you reverted the edit).

Comment: a misunderstanding then, go ahead and clarify your question...my close vote was retracted.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Restored my last edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The battery serial number is written physically on the bottom of the battery:
[image]

Also, in order to ensure at the official repair store that the battery is genuine (which was originally my purpose), the same serial number is on the box the battery comes in:
[image]

...and also in the official papers accompanying the repair part.

Of course, both the box and the battery inside of the box should be sealed and opened for you only just before the replacement operation.

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the serial # on the battery you would have to take the MBA apart?

If you want to do that here are [the instructions](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+Models+A1237+and+A1304+Battery+Replacement/848).

It is easier to use the About This Mac.